# Where is the iOS Developer Menu in General Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, settings

I have many iOS devices and someone showed me their Developer entry in Settings -> General.

None of my devices have this...

How do I enable it? Does the device have to be added to the portal through the IDE of my machine? I can't find a way to get the menu to show up.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled your devices for development through Xcode's organizer?

Comment: what version of iOS do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device to your mac via USB, open Xcode → Organizer and select Use for Development.

Answer (score 0):

They removed it with iOS 6 I think. You have to now go into Mobile Safari Settings and under advanced enable web inspector.